# Overriding structuredClone's serialization in JavaScript class

Tags: javascript, serialization, ecmascript-6, structured-clone

Suppose I have the following class:

```js
class Foo extends EventTarget {
  msg = 'hey';
}
```

Now, suppose I need to transfer an instance of this class via MessagePort to a new Window or Iframe.  This calls `structuredClone()`, which fails:

```js
structuredClone(new Foo());
```

Result:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'structuredClone' on 'Window': EventTarget object could not be cloned.

I think this happens because of [step #20](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/structured-data.html#structuredserializeinternal) in the specification:

> 20. Otherwise, if value is a [platform object](https://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#dfn-platform-object), then throw a "DataCloneError" DOMException.

For my usage, I don't need to serialize the entire state of EventTarget.  I just want to serialize enumerable properties.  This works, for example:

```js
structuredClone({
   ...new Foo()
});
```

But, in cases where I'm serializing large nested structures, looping through each time and each usage is tedious at best, and not great if I'm building a library that I expect others to be able to use.

What I'd like to do is override some class method to clean up the serialization so that it "just works".  If this were JSON, I'd do something like this, with [`toJSON()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#tojson_behavior):

```js
class Foo extends EventTarget {
  msg = 'hey';

  toJSON() {
    return {
      msg: this.msg
    };
  }
}
```

Is there an equivalent of this method for normal built-in structured serialization?

Comment: [This article](https://web.dev/structured-clone/) was interesting with it's JSON hack.

Comment: @scrhartley Yeah, simply serializing/deserializing as JSON doesn't work for me as these objects have dates that I want to retain (without a bunch of hacky string parsing).  There are also some circular object references, which I don't necessarily care about (and could remove with `toJSON()`), but I'd rather see if there's a structured clone version of `toJSON()` first.

Comment: Judging from the lodash implementation of cloneDeep, doing it "properly" is tricky with special handling required for dates, map, sets, regexps, typed arrays, array buffers, etc. So I really think it depends upon exactly how much you want to bite off. You can always use an existing library's implementation directly or else copy it.

Comment: @scrhartley The browser is already doing the structured clone for the purposes of sending the data over a MessagePort.  I simply want to make my class serializable.  I'm assuming there's a method I can implement, perhaps named by Symbol or something.  If there isn't, then that's an answer too.

Comment: Your answer seems to assume there's one form of serialization, or that serialization is a thing. JSON is the closest thing we have to serialisation and it has its set of limitations. Structured clone is a type of cloning and has it's limitations. An instance of a class is just an Object sharing the prototype of its class. A class is just a function with potentially some stuff in its prototype. For structuredClone it's just a method implemented in C++ somewhere. If you don't like it's limitations, then the only leeway you have is the transfer array in the second parameter "options" .

Comment: It is confusing that you speak of [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) in the context of `structuredClone`. The latter provides a deep copy, not serialization.

Comment: I've been wrong about some of this stuff. Here is the [docs about Serializable](Serializable). It says that if an object is serializable then it's one which works with `structuredClone` and for supported types, it then gives a [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm#supported_types) to the supported types for `structuredClone`. So that much I was correct about.

Answer (score 1):

Docs about [Serializable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Serializable_object). It basically says that if it works with `structuredClone` then it's considered serializable and links to the [supported types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm#supported_types).

Here is a completely untested semi-clone implementation that tries to assemble what it thinks will be allowed by `structuredClone` and doesn't try to handle infinite recursion (it would probably cause a stack overflow if it found a loop). This isn't really meant for use, it's probably better to use an existing library's deep clone implementation to achieve the same thing. It's more to demonstrate that trying to handle *everything* is almost impossible and that's why methods such as `structuredClone` effectively just have an internal whitelist and throw an exception if it receives unsupported data.

Since `structuredClone` flattens (gets rid of) the prototype chain, we don't need to worry if we do the same. I've used [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) because it iterates over properties in the prototype as well as the object itself.

```js
function cleanData(data) {
    if (data instanceof Function || data instanceof Promise
            || data instanceof WeakMap || data instanceof WeakSet || data instanceof WeakRef
            || data instanceof FinalizationRegistry || data instanceof ReadableStream) {
        return undefined; // Not supported by structuredClone
    }
    if (data === null || data === undefined
            || data instanceof Date || data instanceof RegExp || data instanceof Error || data instanceof ArrayBuffer || data instanceof DataView || data instanceof Blob
            || ["string", "number", "boolean", "bigint", "symbol"].includes(typeof data) // primitive types
            || data instanceof String || data instanceof Number || data instanceof Boolean || data instanceof BigInt || data instanceof Symbol // wrapped types
            || (!(data instanceof Array) && Object.prototype.toString(data).endsWith("Array]"))) {
        return data; // Not worth cloning.
    }

    if (data instanceof Map) {
        return new Map( Array.from(data)
                .filter(entry => typeof entry[0] !== "function" && typeof entry[1] !== "function")
                .map(entry => [ cleanData(entry[0]), cleanData(entry[1]) ] );
    }
    if (data instanceof Set) {
        return new Set( Array.from(data)
                .filter(val => typeof val !== "function").map(val => cleanData(val)) );
    }
    if (data instanceof Array) {
        return data.filter(val => typeof val !== "function").map(item => cleanData(item));
    }
    
    let constructor = data.constructor;
    if (constructor !== Object && constructor.toString().contains("[native code]")) {
        return undefined; // Unsupported type
    }

    let entries = [];
    for (const key in data) {
        let value = data[key];
        let valType = typeof value;
        if (valType !== "function") {
            if (valType === "object") {
                value = cleanData(value);
            }
            entries.push([key, value]);
        }
    }
    return Object.fromEntries(entries);
}
```

Looking at the supported types, you can see that the above support for Symbol is incorrect and also it doesn't do any check for DOM nodes.